# Eclipse plugin: How to change a JFace Tree model out of a command

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jface, eclipse-jdt

I have created a plugin with a JFace `Tree` similar to this tutorial: [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJFaceTree/article.html)

And I also have defined a menu entry with a command. The handler of the command should change the Model of the tree and update it.  But I have no idea how I can get the right tree view (`TreeViewer` / `ViewPart`) and how I can access the model out of the command handler. Can someone help?

Comment: You created the viewer and wrote the ViewPart class, right?  Write a way to get to the same model and change it, and for the model to notify any viewers that it's been changed.

Comment: Yes, created the viewer and wrote the ViewPart class. But I don't know how to get the right TreeViewer or ViewPart out of another command handler.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1 - Use your own API**

You can inject die active MPart into your Handler and then use part.getObject() to get your contribution class. you can then access your own API to get the Model and the TreeViewer.

```
@Execute
public void executeHandler(@Named(IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_PART) MPart part) {
    MyPart myPart = (MyPart)part.getObject();
    MyModel myModel = myPart.getMyModel();
    TreeViewer viewer = myPart.getMyTreeViewer();
}
```

**Solution 2 - Use DI**

When you initialize your TreeViewer, put it into the IEclipseContext of the Part. You can then have the TreeViewer injected into your Handler.

```
public class MyPart {
    @PostConstruct
    void postConstruct(Composite parent, IEclipseContext context) {
        TreeViewer viewer = new TreeViewer(parent);
        context.set(TreeViewer.class, viewer);
    }
}

public class MyHandler {
    @Execute
    public void executeHandler(TreeViewer viewer) {
    }
}
```

You can do the same thing with the model of course. If there is only one instance of the model (if MyModel is a singleton) you can put it in the context of the application rather that that of the part. A good place to do this would be in an AddOn (or in the LifeCycleHandler).

Alternativly you can define the MyModel class to be @Creatable @Singleton, so it will be created by DI on demand. This is handy, when all the stuff your MyModel needs is in the context already.

My favorite Solution in situations like this is to create a ModelService as an OSGi-Service. OSGi Services are always available through the IEclipseContext.

For more info on DI check out this tutorial by Lars Vogel (Chapters 18, 31, 32):
http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html#dependencyinjectione4
http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html#extentcontext
http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html#ownobjects